# overlap a div on another one-CSS

Tags: css

How can I overlap the yellow bar on the blue bar Here:

```
    .progressBar #bar1 {
        height: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        float: left;
        text-align: right;
        line-height: 22px; 
        width: 0;
        background-color: #0099ff;

    }
    .progressBar #bar2 {

        height: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        text-align: right;
        line-height: 22px; 
        width: 0;
        background-color: yellow;
        z-index:10;               

    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/web_developer_888/CtH9k/3143/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using positions: http://jsfiddle.net/has3jcbp/

```
.progressBar {
                width: 400px;
                height: 22px;
                border: 1px solid #111;
                background-color: #292929;
                position: relative;
            }
            .progressBar #bar1 {
                height: 100%;
                color: #fff;
                float: left;
                text-align: right;
                line-height: 22px;
                width: 0;
                background-color: #0099ff;
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
            }
            .progressBar #bar2 {
                position: absolute;
                top:0;
                left:0;
                height: 100%;
                color: #fff;
                text-align: right;
                line-height: 22px;
                width: 0;
                background-color: yellow;
                z-index:10;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `float: left;` CSS property to your `#bar1` and `#bar2` selectors. See updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CtH9k/3145/)

Comment: That way they are not overlapping, they are side by side

Comment: yes, but in this case percentage value is useless as in your fiddle. Let's look what OP will prefer. Maybe question was not clear enough